# What is the difference in any and all clause in sql?

Tags: sql

I've read many blogs but can't get a clear picture of the difference

Comment: Same as the difference between the words "OR" vs. "AND".

Comment: "You can have any of my toys" versus "you can have all of my toys".

Answer (score 1):

if v1 has to be greater than ANY in col2 then it implies that v1 has to be greater than the minimum in col2. If v1 has to be greater than ALL in col2 then it implies that v1 has to be greater than maximum in col2.

Answer (score 1):

Those are usually used with operators like `> >= < <=` and the are straight forward in that context look at this example:

```sql
select * from employees where salary > any (1000, 150, 75);
select * from employees where dept <= all (select allowed_dept from loan_constraints);
```

the first uses fixed values just to show the syntax the second is more realistic example where the values you compare with are not already known but are read from some other table.

you can always use other ways to write those queries but this is one way and it's readable and clear.

**edit 1**

- less than any equivalent to less than maximum
- less than all equivalent to less than minimum
- equals any equivalent to in
- the same applies to greater than.

Answer (score 0):

If I told you: **Pick *ANY* of the fruit from this basket,** you could take an apple, *or* a pear, *or* a banana.

But if I told you:  **Pick *ALL* of the fruit from this basket,** you would need to take *all* of the apples, *and* *all* of the pears, *and* *all* of the bananas.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it meant that in case of any the data returned by the subquery having any is checked and if atleast 1 passes the condition it shows true but in case of all the rows returned by the subqiery having all is checked and if atleast 1 does not match it shows false